# Keep getting this error in javascript, error: column reference "id" is ambiguous

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, reactjs

In this line `SELECT po.*, du."displayName", du."email" FROM partner_orders as po, ds_user as du WHERE id = ${program.id}` I am keep getting the error **column reference "id" is ambiguous**, how do I solve it?

```
  async getAllParenFinanceOrders() {
    const programOrders = await pool.query(

      `SELECT po.*, du."displayName", du."email"
      FROM partner_orders AS po 
      LEFT JOIN ds_user AS du ON du.id = po."dsUserId" `


    );
    
    console.log("programOrders...", programOrders)

    const partnerPrograms = await Promise.all(
      programOrders.rows.map(async program => {
        const query = await pool.query(
         `SELECT po.*, du."displayName", du."email" FROM partner_orders as po, ds_user as du WHERE id = ${program.id}`
        );
        console.log('query.rows[0]...', query.rows[0])
        return query.rows[0];
      })
    );

    return {
      programs: partnerPrograms
      
    };
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps the lower query's `id` column needs a table prefix.

Comment: In your second query you have opted to ignore the SQL-92 join syntax and not correctly aliased your tables and columns; both tables contain an `id` column, which without an alias to indicate which table's column you mean, it's ambiguous - just like the error states.

Comment: @Stu could you tell em what the fix is please?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which table id you need here but you need to prefix it with one of the table ids for sure:

```
SELECT po.*, du."displayName", du."email" FROM partner_orders as po, ds_user as du WHERE id = ${program.id}`
        );
```

Needs to be re-written as

```
SELECT po.*, du."displayName", du."email" FROM partner_orders as po, ds_user as du WHERE po.id = ${program.id}`
        );
```

OR

```
SELECT po.*, du."displayName", du."email" FROM partner_orders as po, ds_user as du WHERE du.id = ${program.id}`
        );
```

To make the error go away.

Comment: Thanks but now it's not matching the correct email and displayName to the right id :(

Comment: I will need a little more context on what you are trying to do here and what tables partner_orders and ds_users mean. My guess is that there maybe some more information ( another table) that you might be missing here as neither `du.id = ${program.id}` nor `po.id = ${program.id}` sound correct. Are you sure there is no other table you need to look at?